# 301 Redirect *.php to *.html via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

Currently I'm rewriting all incoming requests for *.html to *.php in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php [QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

So /something.html is rewritten to /something.php.

However, /something.php is still directly accessible in the browser. Now I want it to redirect to /something.html when people are accessing it in the browser, so as to avoid 2 distinct URLs for the same page of content.

Is this possible to do in my .htaccess? How? I tried R=301 but it's always a redirect loop or something. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please specify The meaning of =>  [R=301,L] ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this above your `RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ $1.php [QSA]` rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301]
```

That will redirect the browser/client to the same request but with a `.html` instead of a `.php`.

Comment: Can you please specify The meaning of => [L,R=301] ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi They are [Rewrite flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html), the "L" means "Last" which stops rewriting for the current iteration, and the "R" means "Redirect" and the 301 is the redirect code (permanent).